# tableViewCell : image change when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I downloading image and set then in tableViewCell but when Im scrolling the image are changing and after a while they are getting set correctly this is not really good for user this is my code in view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellZ") as? ProductCell {
        let proCell = service.productArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellConfigure(cellProduct: proCell)
        return cell
    }
    return ProductCell()
}
```

and this is my code in UItableViewCell (ProductVC)

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.imageProduct.image = UIImage(named: "sumGray")
}

func cellConfigure(cellProduct : product) {
    productName.text = cellProduct.title
    productFeature.text = cellProduct.info[0].capitalized

    let urlImage = URL(string: cellProduct.pic)!
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            let img = try Data(contentsOf: urlImage)
            DispatchQueue.global().sync {
                self.imageProduct.image = UIImage(data: img)
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

}

I added reuse function but it only make it worse by changing the imageView to default Image 
Im searched in stackoverflow I find some way like reuse but they didn't solve my problem 
I want see current image for every cell
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Before starting the download save the URL and when the download process completes check that the URL didn't change (due to cell reuse). Use downloaded image only if the URL didn't change.
- Don't call UI code from background thread, when setting the downloaded image you should do:

  ```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
     // if the URL didn't change 
     self.imageProduct.image = UIImage(data: img)
  }
  ```